# Switching between 2 jquery isotope instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I've got 2 jquery-isotope instances that 'swap' elements between each other. This works but for some reason I get spaces between the jquery-isotopes. Does someone know how I can remove these whitespaces so that the isotope's arrange correctly. I've made an jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XEYds/

Cheers!

```
var $container = $('#product-masonry');
var $trash = $('#trash-masonry');

$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
});
$trash.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
});

// remove item if clicked

  $container.delegate( '.remove', 'click', function(){
  var remove_id = $(this).data('item');
  $trash.isotope( 'insert',$('#' + remove_id) );
  });
  $trash.delegate( '.remove', 'click', function(){
  var remove_id = $(this).data('item');
  $container.isotope( 'insert',$('#' + remove_id) );
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made 2 new functions in the jquery isotope plugin:

```
throwaway : function( $content, callback ) {
  // remove elements immediately from Isotope instance
  this.$allAtoms = this.$allAtoms.not( $content );
  this.$filteredAtoms = this.$filteredAtoms.not( $content );
  // remove() as a callback, for after transition / animation
  var instance = this;
  var removeContent = function() {
    $('#trash-masonry').append( $content ).isotope( 'appended', $content );
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#trash-masonry').isotope() }, 400);
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#product-masonry').isotope() }, 400);
  };

  if ( $content.filter( ':not(.' + this.options.hiddenClass + ')' ).length ) {
    // if any non-hidden content needs to be removed
    this.styleQueue.push({ $el: $content, style: this.options.hiddenStyle });
    this._sort();
    this.reLayout( removeContent );
  } else {
    // remove it now
    removeContent();
  }

},    

putback : function( $content, callback ) {
  // remove elements immediately from Isotope instance
  this.$allAtoms = this.$allAtoms.not( $content );
  this.$filteredAtoms = this.$filteredAtoms.not( $content );
  // remove() as a callback, for after transition / animation
  var instance = this;
  var removeContent = function() {
    $('#product-masonry').append( $content ).isotope( 'appended', $content );
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#trash-masonry').isotope() }, 400);
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#product-masonry').isotope() }, 400);
  };

  if ( $content.filter( ':not(.' + this.options.hiddenClass + ')' ).length ) {
    // if any non-hidden content needs to be removed
    this.styleQueue.push({ $el: $content, style: this.options.hiddenStyle });
    this._sort();
    this.reLayout( removeContent );
  } else {
    // remove it now
    removeContent();
  }

},
```

and

```
$container.delegate( '.remove', 'click', function(){
    var remove_id = $(this).data('item');
    $container.isotope( 'throwaway',$('#' + remove_id) );
});
$trash.delegate( '.remove', 'click', function(){
    var remove_id = $(this).data('item');
    $trash.isotope( 'putback',$('#' + remove_id) );
});
```

Works like a charm :)